# python - get current time of day in minutes

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I want to get the current time of day in minutes. I found this code online:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 31)
end = datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 1)
diff = end-start
print (diff.days * 1440) + (diff.seconds / 60)
>> 1440.0
```

I'm not sure how i can do this using the `datetime.now()` function, and get the current time of day.

I can compare times if i set the datetime.now() to a variable, and later set it to another variable, and compare them.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

print(now.hour*60 + now.minute)
```